# How to store a stack or long array in database?

Tags: database, algorithm, data-structures, stack, tree-traversal

I am implementing a depth first tree traversal code a large tree. It's single traversal process can span several days because of the long processing time at each node and in between the system might crash or shutdown.

Therefore I want to make the whole process resumable if it the process stops in between for some reason. For that reason I am planning make the whole process backed by persistent datastore which essentially stores the state of the process.

As I figured out that for depth first traversal I will need a Stack type of data structure and which can be realized through a linked list type of array implementation. So my question is if there is some datastore which provides the ability to persist large array to maintain the order of the entities to represent a stack by it. Or if there is some other way through which I can maintain the state of my traversal in a persistent storage.

Thanks.

Comment: Please be more specific in your question. I don't see any problem in storing an array in any type of external storage, filesystem, SQL base or so. If you have just filesystem, when you can use any serialisation language, like YAML or JSON, when use QSL, use unique IDs to describe order or link nodes together.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO: You can implement a custom class of stack behavior using link list. This custom class should be serializable. Storing the state of object intermittently. So even when the system crashes you will loose some data and recreate the complete structure by de-serializing the object from persistent store.